# Shelly Devices and Secure MQTT Connections

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt

Do shelly devices support secure MQTT Connections? If not how can they integrate with GCP IoT Core? It requires that MQTT connections be secure.  What are the options for supporting MQTT on GCP if the devices connecting are not secure? See .https://shelly-api-docs.shelly.cloud/#mqtt-support it says Shelly devices do not support secure MQTT connections. Shelly cloud itself runs on GCP :slightly_smiling_face: but it seems that the devices cannot connect to to IoT core because of they do not support secure connection. (edited)  So this question though is in general too for a device not support secure MQTT Connections what can you do on GCP? how do you support this? Just deploy mosquito brokers but they are not scalable.

Comment: Please, elaborate a bit further your question. What have you tried? What are your investigations?

Comment: I have already found out they Shelly devices do not yet support secure TLS MQTT connections. This may be on the roadmap in the future but its not clear now.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Shelly Pro series (Gen 2 devices) now support TLS for MQTT.